# How do you update another controller's properties and have its value update?

Tags: ember.js

I created the following sample code:

http://ninjy.com:8080/ember/How%20to%20set%20a%20lower%20controller%27s%20variables/#/blah

When you click the button, it's supposed to change the templated text.  It does do this, but the change isn't updated on-screen.  It does work properly when you swap the value and action around:  when the button is in Blah (below the line), and the template value in Application (above the line), then the value is updated on-screen successfully.

Can somebody explain why this happens this way, and how to have the value update properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide lowercased names e.g. `blah` instead of `Blah` when requiring controllers:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['blah'],
  act: function() {
    console.log('act');
    var ctrl = this.get('controllers.blah');
    ctrl.set('myvalue', 'and this is the replacement text');
  }
});
```

[Working jsbin.](http://jsbin.com/iCuVodO/2/edit)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Changing it to lowercase has indeed solved my problem.  Ember could really do with a static checker to give out hints for newbies.  Thank you.  :)

Comment: Out of curiousity, can you elaborate on the right form to use for more complex routes, such as for an ExampleListController (/#/example/list)?