# What is the proper way to capitalise complex controller names in the "needs" property and thereafter?

Tags: ember.js

(This question is a follow-up to [How do you update another controller's properties and have its value update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580903/how-do-you-update-another-controllers-properties-and-have-its-value-update))

I've been advised that I needed to use lowercase for my previous text example.  However, I'm currently working on a slightly more complex version of that code, with more complex routes and more complex controller names.

Can somebody please expand on the proper way to refer to more complex controllers in a method similar to answer posted in the previous question?  For example, an `ExamplesListController` for "/examples/list" (a list route in an examples resource).

I've included the previous jsbin kindly fixed by intuitivepixel:

```js
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['blah'],
  act: function() {
    console.log('act');
    var ctrl = this.get('controllers.blah');
    ctrl.set('myvalue', 'and this is the replacement text');
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/iCuVodO/2/edit

Comment: It's hard when people respond within a minute of eachother with replies that are very close to eachother.  I accepted the Answer with slightly more information, but I'm very grateful to you both.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to refer to more complex controllers is by using the controllers `normalized` name.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['examplesList'],
  act: function() {
    var ctrl = this.get('controllers.examplesList');
    console.log('Controller is: ', ctrl.toString());
  }
});
```

A controller's normalized name does not depend on its url - it is related to how the controller is represented within the ember application's container. To see how this works check out the [DefaultResolver API Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.DefaultResolver.html) or the [normaize method source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0/packages/ember-application/lib/system/resolver.js#L90-L112)

Of course it also helps to have a good understanding of how to name controller's in the first place. See: http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/
For a better understanding of the naming conventions,

Answer (score 3):

To figure out how to reference a controller for the needs array, just take whatever is before the `Controller` part and lowercases the first letter.

For `ExamplesListController`:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['exampleList'],
  act: function() {
    console.log('act');
    var ctrl = this.get('controllers.exampleList');
    ctrl.set('myvalue', 'and this is the replacement text');
  }
})
```

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/IpeHima/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Small clarification for some:

If your controller class was `ExamplesListController`

the `needs` parameters would be:

`needs: ['examplesList']`,

**Rule of thumb**: Lowercase the first letter, and drop 'Controller' from the end. (Singular/plural is not part of the normalization scheme, only the capitalization).